# Работа textContent

Tags: javascript

Перебираю массив и создаю элемент. Элемент создается добавляется на страницу, но его содержимого не видно. Причем в консоле содержимое прописано

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на самой странице не видно. Подскажите почему?

```js
var notes = [];
 var tcor = 0;
 var lcor = 0;
 var indicator = 0;
 var addfirstlevel = document.getElementById('addfirstlevel').onclick = addfirstlevel;
 function addfirstlevel(){
  var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
  dialog.showModal();
  var date = document.getElementById('date');
  var time = document.getElementById('time');
  var dateObj = new Date();
  date.value = dateObj.toISOString().slice(0,10)
  time.value = dateObj.getHours() + ':' + dateObj.getMinutes();
 }
 var add = document.getElementById('add').onclick = add;
 function add (){
  var header = document.getElementById('header');
  var notetext = document.getElementById('note-text');
  var date = document.getElementById('date');
  var time = document.getElementById('time');
  function far ()
  {
   console.log("aga");
  }
  function addmain(){
   notes.map(item, index, )
  }
  if (header.value === "" || notetext.value === "")
  {
   var message = document.getElementById('fail');
   message.style.display = "block";
  }else
  { 
   
   tcor+=10;
   lcor+=10;
   indicator+=1;
   var obg = {
    id: indicator,
    header: header.value,
    date: date.value,
    time: time.value,
    notetext: notetext.value,
    left: lcor,
    top: tcor
   };
   notes.push(obg);
   notes.forEach(function(item){
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var one = document.createElement("div");
    var two = document.createElement("p");
    var tree = document.createElement("p");
    var four = document.createElement("p");
    var five = document.createElement("p");
    one.className = "note";
    one.style.left = item.left + "px";
    one.style.top = item.top + "px";
    two.className = "item-of-note";
    tree.className = "item-of-note";
    four.className = "item-of-note";
    five.className = "item-of-note";
    two.textContent = "item.header";
    tree.textContent = item.date;
    four.textContent = item.time;
    five.textContent = item.notetext;
    one.appendChild(two);
    one.appendChild(tree);
    one.appendChild(four);
    one.appendChild(five);
    one.onclick = far;
    main.appendChild(one);
   })

   dialog.close();
  }

 }
```

```css
#main
{ width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
 background-color: #ecbb32;
 position: relative;
}

#addfirstlevel
{
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 float:right;
 margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 background: green;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.plus
{
 background: white;
 height: 20px; 
 width: 6px;
 position: relative; 
 left: 17px;
 top: 10px;
}
.plus:after 
{
 content: "";
 height: 6px; 
 width: 20px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute; 
 left: -7px; 
 top: 7px;
}
.form
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.note
{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 position: absolute;
 background: #fdfb35;

}

.item-of-note
{
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 font-size: 10px;
}
input
{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button
{
 margin-top: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: green;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}


dialog::backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

p
{
 display: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="addfirstlevel">
   <div class="plus"></div>
  </div>
  <dialog id="dialog">
   <div class="form">
    <input id="header" maxlength="20" placeholder="Заголовок" type="text">
    <input id="date" type="date">
    <input id="time" type="time">
    <textarea id="note-text" placeholder="Текст заметки" maxlength="44"></textarea>
    <button id="add">Добавить</button>
   </div>
   <p>Заметка размещена</p>
   <p id="fail">Проверьте<br>данные</p>
  </dialog>
 </div>
```

Comment: У меня ваш код полностью работает и всё видно, значит вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Добавил весь код. Делаю учебный проект заметки, там крестик нажимаешь и оно добовляет

Comment: Это абсолютно точно не весь код, потому что в нём как минимум нет html-элемента с id `main` и нет переменной `notes`. Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы мы могли запустить его у себя и увидеть вашу проблему, иначе вам здесь не помогут.

Comment: О вроде добавилось

Comment: В вашем CSS прямым текстом прописано `p { display: none` — то есть скрыть все элементы `<p>`. Поэтому его и не видно

Comment: да только сча понял. Спасибо. Вот блин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В devtools смотреть надо было:

[image: скриншот]